# Add Button to separate cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I need to add button to separate cells

Button in yellow circle

[image: Button in yellow circle]

i can add to all cells like `[cell addSubview:myButt];` but it works to all cells, i need only for 5, 6, 7, 8 cells;

Do i need to write a custom `UITableViewCell`?

And that line(black arrows), as i understand it is Section, how can i create it with no title, with line(image) and in middle of the table? Thank's to all.

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: write some check like if(indexPath.section ==1) & if(indexPath.row==0){[cell addSubview:myButt]; } else if(indexPath.row ==1){[cell addSubview:myButt];} and so on. its really easy. try for your self. good luck

Comment: You *can* do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using `viewWithTag:`, but it will quickly become annoying to maintain.  You *should* subclass UITableViewCell: view logic belongs in a UIView subclass.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add button in cellforrow method :

```
If (indexpath.row == 3 || indexpath.row == 4 || indexpath.row == 5 || indexpath.row == 3) 
{
   // add button here
   // tag button here
   Button.tag = indexpath.row ;
}
```

Comment: Then the button will get reused when the user scrolls up and down.

Comment: It will get reused but it will also be always visible even though it's not the right cell.

Comment: Yes, you can use tagging, but your answer doesn't demonstrate that

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I still think it's insufficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can hide your section header like this :

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
    // or 1.0 as per your line
}
```

For buttons on your cells, you have to create a custom cell Class and then use that in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. You can also use tags for this. You can do it like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell  alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
  if(indexPath.row>=5 && indexPath.row <=8)
   {
    //adding buttons to custom cell
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tag` property of `UIView` to keep track of your button but I'd really recommend to use a custom `UITableViewCell`. With that being said, below is the code you could use. It is optimized to not add the same button over and over but just when you need it, and hide it in cases you don't need it.

```
static int kButtonViewTag = 3294802;
UIButton *button = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:kButtonViewTag];
BOOL shouldDisplayButton = indexpath.row == 5 || indexpath.row == 6 || indexpath.row == 7 || indexpath.row == 8;

// If the button should be displayed and is not
//
if (shouldDisplayButton)  {

    // Add button here
    //
    if (!button) {
        button = // Init your button
        button.tag = kButtonViewTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button]
    }
    else if (button.isHidden) {
        button.hidden = NO;
    }
}


// If the button should not be displayed but is
//
else if (!shouldDisplayButton && button && !button.isHidden) {
    button.hidden = NO;
}
```

---

And then for your section:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat tableWidth = tableView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat padding = 10; // Add some padding

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 0, tableWidth - padding * 2, 1)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]; //your background color...
    return view;
}
```